# Storing an arraylist of custom objects (which have Strings, Dates, Lists, and more as fields) in shared preferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, save, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save an arraylist of clients in shared preferences, however I am getting out of memory error. I am new to this and can't figure out how to do this? I looked at a lot of pages on stackoverflow, but couldn't find one that would work for me or that also had an `ArrayList` of custom objects, where every object contains more ArrayLists with custom objects.

client object:

```
public class Client implements Serializable, Comparable<Client> {
    private int clientID;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String url;
    private Double turnover;
    private String visitAddress;
    private String visitCity;
    private String visitZipcode;
    private String visitCountry;
    private String postalAddress;
    private String postalCity;
    private String postalZipcode;
    private String postalCountry;
    private Drawable clientImage;
    private List<Contact> contactList =  new ArrayList<Contact>();
    private List<Project> projectList = new ArrayList<Project>();
    private List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    private List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();


    public Client(int clientID, String Name, String Phone, String Email, String URL, Double Turnover,
                  String VisitAddress, String VisitCity, String VisitZipcode, String VisitCountry,
                  String PostalAddress, String PostalCity, String PostalZipcode, String PostalCountry,
                  List contactList, List projectList, List taskList, List orderList){
            super();
        this.clientID = clientID;
        this.name = Name;
            this.phone = Phone;
            this.email = Email;
            this.url = URL;
            this.turnover = Turnover;
            this.visitAddress = VisitAddress;
            this.visitCity = VisitCity;
            this.visitZipcode = VisitZipcode;
            this.visitCountry = VisitCountry;
            this.postalAddress = PostalAddress;
            this.postalCity = PostalCity;
            this.postalZipcode = PostalZipcode;
            this.postalCountry = PostalCountry;
            this.contactList = contactList;
            this.projectList = projectList;
            this.taskList = taskList;
            this.orderList = orderList;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public Double getTurnover() {

        return turnover;
    }

    public String getVisitAddress() {
        return visitAddress;
    }

    public String getVisitCity() {
        return visitCity;
    }

    public String getVisitZipcode() {
        return visitZipcode;
    }

    public String getVisitCountry() {
        return visitCountry;
    }

    public String getPostalAddress() {
        return postalAddress;
    }

    public String getPostalCity() {
        return postalCity;
    }

    public String getPostalZipcode() {
        return postalZipcode;
    }

    public String getPostalCountry() {
        return postalCountry;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContactList(){
        return contactList;
    }

    public List<Project> getProjectList(){
        return projectList;
    }

    public List<Task> getTaskList(){
        return taskList;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrderList() {
        return orderList;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setTurnover(Double turnover) {
        this.turnover = turnover;
    }

    public void setVisitAddress(String visitAddress) {
        this.visitAddress = visitAddress;
    }

    public void setVisitCity(String visitCity) {
        this.visitCity = visitCity;
    }

    public void setVisitZipcode(String visitZipcode) {
        this.visitZipcode = visitZipcode;
    }

    public void setVisitCountry(String visitCountry) {
        this.visitCountry = visitCountry;
    }

    public void setPostalAddress(String postalAddress) {
        this.postalAddress = postalAddress;
    }

    public void setPostalCity(String postalCity) {
        this.postalCity = postalCity;
    }

    public void setPostalZipcode(String postalZipcode) {
        this.postalZipcode = postalZipcode;
    }

    public void setPostalCountry(String postalCountry) {
        this.postalCountry = postalCountry;
    }

    public Drawable getClientImage() {
        return clientImage;
    }

    public void setClientImage(Drawable clientImage) {
        this.clientImage = clientImage;
    }

    public int getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }

    public void setClientID(int clientID) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }
```

underlying project object: (also with list of custom objects)

```
public class Project implements Serializable, Comparable<Project>{

    private String clientName;
    private String projectName;
    private String projectDiscription;
    private String  projectStatus;
    private GregorianCalendar projectDate;
    private List<TimeSheet> projectTimeRegestrationList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<WorkOrder> workOrderList = new ArrayList<WorkOrder>();


    public Project(String clientName, String projectName, String projectDiscription, String projectStatus, GregorianCalendar projectDate, List projectTimeRegestrationList, List workOrderList) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.projectDiscription = projectDiscription;
        this.projectStatus = projectStatus;
        this.projectDate = projectDate;
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.projectTimeRegestrationList = projectTimeRegestrationList;
        this.workOrderList = workOrderList;
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    public String getProjectDiscription() {
        return projectDiscription;
    }

    public void setProjectDiscription(String projectDiscription) {
        this.projectDiscription = projectDiscription;
    }

    public String getProjectStatus() {
        return projectStatus;
    }

    public void setProjectStatus(String projectStatus) {
        this.projectStatus = projectStatus;
    }

    public GregorianCalendar getProjectDate() {
        return projectDate;
    }

    public void setProjectDate(GregorianCalendar projectDate) {
        this.projectDate = projectDate;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public List<TimeSheet> getProjectTimeRegestrationList() {
        return projectTimeRegestrationList;
    }

    public List<WorkOrder> getWorkOrderList() {
        return workOrderList;
    }
```

now my specific question: is it possible to save this inside shared preferences, if yes, how do i do this, if no, how should i then locally safe this data.

Comment: Use Gson library to convert your object to json string and vice-versa. And save string in preferences.

Comment: @USKMobility, this is not working for me, i get a OutOfMemoryError, but does this even work for custom objects, that hold lists with custom objects, that also hold lists with custom objects

Comment: You can always save your data into files somewhere in project or at specific path in your computer.

Comment: You should implement Serializable on your custom object and use the write Serializable of SharedPreferences

Comment: @D.Blazer check the answer it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use json to store them as a string in sharedpreference

for example if you want to store an object of your client class contaning a url ,country and phone

just write the following

```
try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
                JSONObject object1=new JSONObject();
                object1.put("url","myurl");
                object1.put("phone","myphonenumber");
                object1.put("country","mycountry");
                jsonArray.put(object1);

                //adding another object
                JSONObject object2=new JSONObject();
                object2.put("url","anotherurl");
                object2.put("phone","anotherphonenumber");
                object2.put("country","anothercountry");
                jsonArray.put(object2);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and than simply  save it as a string by calling  `jsonArray.toString()` in sharedpreference

and if your object that you want to store contains a list of another object you can easily save like for example if you have a url, country, and phone number which you want to save plus a list of another object containing the first and lastname you can save list as json object itself just like you did for the url,phone number and country as shown below

```
try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
                JSONObject object1=new JSONObject();
                object1.put("url","myurl");
                object1.put("phone","myphonenumber");
                object1.put("country","mycountry");

                //saving a list of another object contaning firstname and lastname
                JSONArray listArray=new JSONArray();

                //supposing your list contains 10 objects
                for(int f=0;f<10;f++){
                    JSONObject listobject=new JSONObject();
                    listobject.put("firstname","myfirstname");
                    listobject.put("lastname","mylastname");
                    listArray.put(listobject);
                }
                //now the list array we added as an object of the jsonArray variable
                JSONObject object2=new JSONObject(); //object2 containing the list of firstname and lastname
                object2.put("list",listArray.toString());
                jsonArray.put(object1);//object1 contains the url, phone, and country
                jsonArray.put(object2);//object2 contains the list of firstname and lastname


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: this is a great method that works wel aslong as the hierarchy doesnt go so deep, ended up using this after a kinda massive structure change, cause my hierarchy went about 5 arraylists of custom objects deep. and this only work great with 2 at most. but is this the only way, and did i just structure my app really stupid at first, or is there a good way to save arraylists of custom objects with a very deep hierarchy .

Comment: @D.Blazer no it can work as deep as you want ,you can like add a function that returns you a jsonobject for each class and another function that returns you a jsonarray  of an  arraylist of objects of this class which you simply return it as another jsonobject . i already done it to save a class containing at least 4 arraylist of different objects but it will require more work than using Serializable but it's not hard at all